# Dimension of adjoint representation of symplectic real Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

How do I find the dimension of the adjoint representation of the real symplectic Lie algebra, $sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$?

I know that it's irreducible, but other than that I am not sure.

Comment: This might be related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051400/is-the-symplectic-group-operatornamesp2n-mathbbr-simple

Comment: @MrYouMath so does that mean that the dimension of the adjoint representation is the same as that of $sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$, i.e $n^2+4n$?

Comment: The dimension of the adjoint representation is always equal to the dimension of the Lie algebra.

Comment: The dimension of $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is $n(2n+1)$, the number of independent real *2n×2n* symmetric matrices used in the defining representation of the algebra. So the adjoint has that dimension; you are not asking for a convenient basis, are you?